# My delete operation is not working properly?

Tags: javascript, object

This is my delete code, it works only on first invokation?

```
const byId = (state = {}, action) => { 
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'REMOVE_TODO':
      return  Object.keys(state).filter( key => { 
        return state[key].id !== action.id 
      }).reduce((acc,key) => Object.defineProperty(acc, key, {
        value: state[key], }),{});          
          default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

My state object is like this:

```
{"abcd1": {id: "abcd1", text: "hello world"}, "efgh2": {id: "efgh2", text: "hello there"}
```

So what happens is I can delete on the first invokation, then my object becomes all empty when I try to invoke again? or only {} . Can't figure out why?

Answer (score 0):

Well I would prefer to shape my state object like:

```
[{id: "abcd1", text: "hello world"},{id: "efgh2", text: "hello there"}]
```

since it's just redundant to repeat the object key and the todo id if they are the same.
Then, in the reducer you can have something like:

```
const byId = (state = [], action) => { 
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'REMOVE_TODO':
      return state.filter((todo) => todo.id != action.id)
    default:   
      return state;
};
```